# Class D Amplifier Design Producing Lots of EMI

Tags: audio, noise, class-d

I recently completed a class D amplifier PCB design based around the TPA3118D2.

It's been working very well for me and sounds clean on the output, but it appears to be producing a noticeable amount of EMI. If I turn one on in my workshop I can visually see noise increase on my oscilloscope, while I'm measuring an unconnected circuit.

This happens only when the amplifiers are on, and only when the outputs are unmuted by pulling the MUTE pin low. It's also strange because the audio output itself sounds clean, the noise only shows up elsewhere.

Here is my schematic and PCB layout, is there anything I should look at that would be causing this behavior?

[image]

[image]

Edit:

-Could it be the 2 layer board, needs to be 4 layer?

-Is there any thing in the selection of output filter components that might be causing this? Specifically looking at the ferrite bead because those components and their requirements for audio are never well documented. Here is the ferrite bead component I used:

https://jlcpcb.com/partdetail/VishayIntertech-ILHB1206ER121V/C124704

-Is there anything in my input pre-amplifier design that might be causing this?

Comment: What node is the dark blue flood? I didn't see any vias connecting it to GND for the output capacitors (C20, C23 etc.) <-- you appear to be using the top copper for GND and this might be a significant problem. What does the data sheet recommend regards grounding?

Comment: Sorry I meant C20 and C24 <-- they have a tortuous path back to GND compared to C23 and C21.

Comment: Dark blue is ground. Both top and bottom are traces plus a ground plane.

Comment: They are connected to a jumper header that connected them to either the left side pre-amp or ground for stereo / mono operation.

Comment: If you disconnect the speaker leads (replace with 8R resistors on the shortest possible wire) what happens to the noise level?

Comment: I would recommend "stitching the design". Make sure, that all ground tracks are connected to the ground plane via Vias and take special care for all GND pads of capacitors and ICs. Also make sure, that the GND layers themselfs are connected via Vias in !multiple! places. Also, you could add decoupling (10p,100n,1U) directly to the PWR connector.

Comment: If the four through-holes in the corners are used for mounting, ensure none of the components PWR, GND, L+, and L- are installed.  Check them with a magnifier to make absolutely sure there are no tiny solder or flux bridges.

Comment: How many PCB layers and what’s your stack up?

Comment: @winny two layers, traces on both sides, but most of them on top with bottom being more of the dedicated ground plane.

Comment: @user_1818839 when I disconnect the speakers the noise disappears. When I connect a dummy resistor I see noise again, more or less at a similar level to the speakers

Comment: @rdtsc they are not connected to anything at present

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent sounds like adding more vias to get better grounding is the main thing? Is there anything else that might account for this?

Comment: Move to 4 layers with solid ground and Vcc inner layers.

Comment: @winny Is there any solution that doesn't involve a 4 layer board?

Comment: Crapton of decoupling capacitors, RC, CM and DM filters?

Comment: @winny what is crapton?

Comment: "large amounts"